# converting images for matchTemplate()

Tags: python, opencv

I want to call this function in python

> function matchTemplate()

I have tried this

```
while 1:
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    img = np.array(img)
    img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    match = cv.imread('match.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    match = cv.cvtColor(match, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    match = cv.cvtColor(match, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    result = cv.matchTemplate(img[0], match[0], cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    cv.imshow('bla', result)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows
        break
    time.sleep(0.2)
print('done')
```

The only issue is that, i have to convert those images to grayscale and that is going to be problem in future, because i want to match really similar images and only difference between them is color. When I run that code, I get output which is just gray, except a long, thin, white line on the left side.

When i add this to the code and run it

```
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)

    print('Best match top left position: %s' % str(max_loc))
    print('Best match: %s' % max_val)
```

It outputs this, even when the template isn't anywhere on the screen:
Best match top left position: (0, 0)
Best match confidence: 1.0

Comment: I think you can convert the 3 channels of a rgb (or bgr) image to grayscale seperately and use them for matching.

Comment: You can keep using the template matching on grayscale. Then return to the color originals and compare the colors where the template was found. (Simple SAD or SSD comparison should work.)

Comment: You can match the tenplates for every channel separately and only if positions agree in all channels accept it as a match.